# Simple crontab script on works

Tags: cron

The following crontab entry doesn't work:

```
 * * * * if pgrep wine || pgrep -f minecraft; then systemctl stop nbminer; else systemctl start nbminer; fi
```

But if I put the exact command in a bash script and then use it in the crontab it works:

```
 * * * * /home/braulio/gitconfig/scripts/minerctl
```

At the beginning of the crontab I'm using `SHELL=/bin/bash`, but it doesn't help.

Anything am I missing?

Comment: You’re missing that using a script is indeed the easiest solution when your batch job requires anything more than “do something at this time” and the “something” comes with more conditions.

Comment: gaming is not on topic for serverfault, just use it as a script file. sometimes it is reuiqred to use single/double quotes that it works